# How can I initialize glut without the main line arugments?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++-2010

In c++, we are used to see that opengl is installed in main function.Such as-

```
int main(int argv,char **argc){
         glutInit(&argv,argc);
         glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);

..............................
}
```

But without this main function,how can we declare opengl in other sub functions?
Such as-

```
int main(){
...........}

int installopengl(int argv,char **argc){
glutInit(&argv,argc);


glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);

..............................
}
```

Comment: How about calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is defiantly not recommended, you can always do this:

```
int i = 0;
glutInit(&i, NULL);
```

The issue with doing it this way is that you won't be able to pass any information to the glut library from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstood - why cant you directly call the function  like below ?

```
int main(int argv,char **argc) {
    installopengl(argv, argc);

    ...........
}

int installopengl(int argv,char **argc) {
    glutInit(&argv,argc);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);

    ..............................
}
```

Comment: Probably, because he/she tried to start learning OpenGL, before he/she actually knew the language itself.

Comment: Oh,, yes now i get it.Looks like i have to call it in my main function.Thank you brother,@Vallentin .And i am a noob and started learning opengl.                                                         Again thanks to uou brother (Y)

Answer (score 2):

Please get your terminology right. OpenGL is not *installed* in a program. It get's **initialized**.

Also the pattern you quoted is GLUT initialization. GLUT is not OpenGL, but a simple windowing framework, that creates a OpenGL context for you to use to draw to the window. But there are several other frameworks as well.

Then you seem to completely misunderstand what the main function does. `main` is the program entry point, the very first function that gets called in a process *after* the runtime environment has been set up. main can call any function, and you can simply call a dedicated framework initialization there. If it needs parameters from main you simply pass them along.

Comment: Now i realized.Thanks to you brother. :)